# Declaring increment variable in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to declare a variable that would increment everytime a condition is met since I need the number of time the condition was met for the output.

Variables:

```
String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

-----this part is inside an if-----
String yourname = request.getParameter("yourname").toLowerCase();
            String crushname = request.getParameter("crushname").toLowerCase();
            yourname = yourname.replace(" ","");
            crushname = crushname.replace(" ","");
            String[] a_yourname = yourname.split("(?!^)");
            String[] a_crushname = crushname.split("(?!^)");
```

Basically I'm trying to do this PHP code in Java:

```
if($yourname[$x] == $letters[$y]){
        if($yourname[$x] == 'a'){
            $y_a++;
        }
        if($yourname[$x] == 'b'){
            $y_b++;
        }
        if($yourname[$x] == 'c'){
            $y_c++;
        }
```

}

This is my Java part:

```
int y_a=0;
int y_b=0;
            for(int x=0;x<a_yourname.length;x++){
                for(int y=0;y<letters.length;y++){
                    if(a_yourname[x] == letters[y]){
                            if(a_yourname[x] == "a"){
                                    y_a++;
                            }
                            if(a_yourname[x] == "b"){
                                    y_b++;
                            }
```

Don't mind the missing closing tags, this will always return 0 whenever I print y_a, well I guess its because I initialize it to hold 0, but how do I make it so that the initialized value wont overwrite the incremented one?

I know this is very simple for some but I'm really a PHP guy and I really don't know much about Java.

Comment: what is $ in your code ? is it PHP code?

Comment: yup thats php and im converting it to java, since it was much more easy for me to formulate the logic in php

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. See any Java book for details.

Comment: i'm sorry im use to php not java. atleast i learned something new today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is, that you try to compare Strings using `==`.

In Java `==`, however, just compares the object identity (when used with objects, such as Strings) and not their contents!

To compare the contents of an object in Java use `equals()` (for equality) or `compareTo()` (for ordering). So in your case it should say:

```
if( a_yourname[x].equals( letters[y] ) ){
    if( "a".equals( a_yourname[x] ) ){
      y_a++;
    }
    if( "b".equals( a_yourname[x] )){
      y_b++;
    }
}
```

Assuming, that you really mean String compare here.

If you mean to compare `char` or single characters, turn the `"` around `"a"` to `'` to mark it as such!

Comment: is it just similar to a_yourname[x].equals("a")?

Comment: @magicianIam It is. This notation just causes no error, when `a_yourname[x]` is null. In that case `a_yourname[x].equals("a")` would return a null pointer exception.

Comment: so its best to use "a".equals( a_yourname[x] ) instead of the other one? though i still get 0 result.

Comment: @magicianIam It is. Can you give us some sample data for the `a_yourname` and `letter` arrays?

Comment: added the variable declaration for a_yourname and letters

Comment: @magicianIam After some short testing, I think, you forgot to change the first `if`-clause. There it's the same. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

a_yourname[x] == "a" don't work in java. You need
a_yourname[x].equals("a") instead.

Or a_yourname[x] == 'a' if a_yourname is an array of char.

Comment: @MTilsted a_yourname[x] == 'a' tried this but said incoperable string and char error. got any idea for the increment? :)

Comment: So use the equals method. a_yourname[x].equals("a") - Your problem is that your equal newer get true

Comment: will do then, wait is that why my increment wont work?

Answer (score 0):

Just decalare you variable out of the function where your code is.

for example:

```
int y_a=0;
int y_b=0;

void function()
{
 for(int x=0;x<a_yourname.length;x++){
                for(int y=0;y<letters.length;y++){
                    if(a_yourname[x] == letters[y]){
                            if(a_yourname[x] == "a"){
                                    y_a++;
                            }
                            if(a_yourname[x] == "b"){
                                    y_b++;
                            }
}
```

Comment: how do i do that in jsp? its not inside a function.

Comment: could you put all the file .jsp?